# Using a TextureArray in ModernGL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, textures, python-moderngl

I recently started using ModernGL, and today I would like to start working with texture arrays. I'm just stuck on how to pass the individual subtextures in Moderngl? In OpenGL I would call `glTexSubImage3D`. However, in the ModernGL documentation, `Context.texture_array` takes 3 arguments: `size`, `components`, and `data`. I think `data` is supposed to be all the images stacked? How would I go about this using PIL and possibly numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read each image separately and append the images to a list. Finally convert the list to an `numpy.array`.
In the following snippet `imageList` is a list of filenames and `width` and `height` is the size of an individual image (the images must all be the same size):

```
def createTextureArray(imageList, width, height)

    depth = len(imageList)

    dataList = []
    for filename in imageList:
        
        image = Image.open(filename)
        if width != image.size[0] or height != image.size[1]:
            raise ValueError(f"image size mismatch: {image.size[0]}x{image.size[1]}")
        
        dataList.append(list(image.getdata()))

    imageArrayData = numpy.array(dataList, numpy.uint8)

    components = 4 # 4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB
    context.texture_array((width, height, depth), components, imageArrayData)
```